# Connected Objects in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am exploring TS and Angular. I wanted to update my parent component array with and EventEmitter call. I did it so far but then noticed I don't need to cause my parent array is connected to my component variables (I guess so, that why I ask).

I generate my child component dynamically and initialize my child objects from the parent array. Is my template-task task$ Object so a reference to to the `$task` object from my parent array ?

Parent component:

```
<div *ngIf="task" class="elements">
    <app-template-task (ping)="update($event)" [task$]="task" *ngFor="let task of $tasks"></app-template-task>
</div>
```

Child component HTML:

```
        <div class="checkbox">
        <img *ngIf="task$.done" (click)="changeStatus($event)" src="../../../assets/checked.png" alt="">
        <img *ngIf="!task$.done" (click)="changeStatus($event)" src="../../../assets/unchecked.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="task$.todoText" (blur)="changeText($event)" placeholder="Name des Todo punkts">
    </div>
```

TS from parent:

```
  public task: boolean;
  public taskDone: boolean;
  public $tasks: Todo[];
  public $tasksdone: Todo[];

  constructor() {
    this.task = true;
    this.taskDone = true;
    this.$tasks = [
      {
        id: 0,
        todoText: "Task 1",
        done: false,
        position: 1
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        todoText: "Task 2",
        done: false,
        position: 2
      }
    ]
    this.$tasksdone = []
  }
```

TS from Child:

```
@Input() task$!: Todo; //! erlaubt es das theoretisch task auch null sein darf
@Output() ping: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

constructor() {
}

  public changeStatus(event? : any): void{
    this.task$.done = !this.task$.done
    this.sendEvent("changed")
  } 

  public changeText(event? : any): void{
    console.log(this.task$.todoText)
    this.sendEvent("textChanged")
  }

  private sendEvent(eventIdentifier: string): void{
    const eventObject: Eventping = {
      label: eventIdentifier,
      object: this.task$
    }
    this.ping.emit(eventObject)
  }
```

Comment: When you pass an object or array, pass "by reference": You only have an unique "element" -really you pass a memory location-. When you pass a number or a string you pass "by value", you have two "elements" -you pass a copy of the value of the variable-.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're passing a reference up there: `[task$]="task"`

Having references in data bindings is good. Mutating objects in child components on the other hand is a bad thing to do.
So you should only use your data from an `@Input`, not change it.

The only place to change data is the parent component (where it's originally located).

I would recommend you making your child component a "dumb" one (means that it only shows data and tells parent what's going on, and the parent changes the data accordingly).

**child.component.html** :

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <img *ngIf="task.done" (click)="changeStatus()" src="../../../assets/checked.png" alt="">
    <img *ngIf="!task.done" (click)="changeStatus()" src="../../../assets/unchecked.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="text">
    <input type="text" [value]="task.todoText" (change)="changeText($event)" placeholder="Name des Todo punkts">
</div>
```

**child.component.ts** :

```
@Input() task: Todo;
// you can check docs on Partial here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype
@Output() ping: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<Partial<Todo>>();

constructor(){}

public changeStatus(): void {
  this.ping.next({ done: !this.task$.done });
} 

public changeText(newText: string): void {
  this.ping.next({ todoText: newText });
}
```

Then your parent component should handle the updates and finally change your precious data :)

**parent.component.html** :

```
<div *ngIf="task" class="elements">
   <app-template-task (ping)="update(idx, $event)" [task]="task" *ngFor="let task of $tasks; let idx = index"></app-template-task>
</div>
```

**parent.component.ts** :

```
public task = true;
public taskDone = true;
public tasks: Todo[] = [
  {
    id: 0,
    todoText: "Task 1",
    done: false,
    position: 1
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    todoText: "Task 2",
    done: false,
    position: 2
  }
];
public tasksDone: Todo[] = [];

constructor(){
}

update(taskIdx: number, changes: Partial<Todo>) {
  // here we update reference by creating a new array with the .map method
  // it's needed for the Angular Change Detection worked.
  this.tasks = this.tasks.map((task, idx) => {
    if (idx === taskIdx) return { ...task, ...changes };
    return task;
  });
  // do anything else if needed
}
```

Basically that's it. I hope it'll help :)

Comment: @realShao , if my answer helped you, please mark it as a valid solution, so I could earn some points for it :)